Ruqyah Sheets Quran with out diacritics to remove sihr
Assalamualaikum,
I'm planning to make ruqyah sheets to remove sihr. The challenges I'm facing is that I need Quran with out diacritics. Is there any way to get Quran with out diacritics?
Please help me
